# How do I run "dir pattern /s /b" in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to achieve the same output in Powershell as I would get by running `dir [pattern] /s /b` in cmd.exe.

Recursive directory search, with a filter, printing out just the full file paths of found files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Select Fullname`

(`Dir` being a PowerShell alias for `Get-ChildItem`).

`Fullname` includes the Path (like /B), if you just want the file names, use `Select Name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem . -recurse | Select-Object Name
```

the . means "this folder" a .. would mean the parent folder of this folder. This is an example of the output that I get:

```
Name
----
0409
1033
AdvancedInstallers
appmgmt
ar-SA
BestPractices
bg-BG
Boot
catroot
catroot2
CodeIntegrity
com
config
cs
cs-CZ
da-DK
de
```

to include a pattern use -filter or -include. Personally I use -include because it seems more intuitive to me. It also allows multiple patterns:

```
Get-ChildItem . -recurse -include *.exe, *.dll | Select-Object Name
```